# If the bomb was remotely triggered by a phone call, why wasn't the detonation ever mentioned?

Tags: jack-ryan-tv

At the end of the final episode of the first season of *Jack Ryan*, we see

> Suleiman gets shot, and Jack arrives to the body as the remote bomb is connecting on the phone. It seemed that the call connected.

Why wasn't the detonation ever mentioned afterward?

I may be mistaken as to whether it actually connected, but it seemed it went through.

Answer (score 2):

The call didn't connect if I recall correctly.

He was chasing Suleiman out of the tube station, where he did not have signal for the phone. He shot him as a last resor,t because he knew he would get signal soon. When he checked the phone I believe it was the standard "no signal" tone or "couldn't connect voiceline".

Comment: Having coincidentally watched this episode this week, the phone did specifically show that it was searching for a connection, not that it had found one. The showrunners made the mistake of showing the connection loading animation (going from empty to full) only once. This is probably a repeating animation (which indicates _attempts_ at making a connection), but because they show precisely one loop of that animation, it comes across as if the connection is being established.